# Issue with Termux bootstrap

Tags: android, termux

After downloading Termux from the Google Play store, FDroid, and Github, I got the error

```
Unable to Install
Termux was unable to install the bootstrap packages.
Check your network connection and try again.
```

I looked through Github and found this [this reply](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/1761#issuecomment-342426998) saying to try to connect to http://termux.net/bootstrap/ in a browser. I tried with the phone I'm trying to put Termux on (Galaxy s5 with Android 6.0.1) and got a response saying 'connection timed out'. I tried on my desktop which is on the same network, and got the same response. I made a simple python script using the requests module on a Replit server and got the same response with error 522.
It seems like the Termux.net website isnt working for some reason, maybe because of a WiFi setting that has to get changed? What else do I try?

Comment: For reference [this comment](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/1761#issuecomment-602012756) and for a possible workaround see: [How to install Termux on old Android 5 devices ? (using the official archive)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/245738/3573)

Answer (score 2):

Issue is that old links for bootstrap package for Android versions 5 and 6 are not available anymore, for example domain https://termux.net is down and you can not access it.

You can fix this issue by following this wiki:
https://github.com/termux/termux-app/wiki/Termux-on-android-5-or-6

You can install artifacts from this link:
https://github.com/termux/termux-app/actions/runs/2619084610

*Zipped APK file **termux-app_v0.118.0+605dd6c-apt-android-5-github-debug_armeabi-v7a** can be downloaded from this link:
https://github.com/termux/termux-app/suites/7230045376/artifacts/289921940

**Note: Direct APK link will only work if you are signed in with your GitHub account*

Comment: It looks like the packages are now expired :(

Comment: you're right unfortunately :(

Comment: It looks like the next Termux update will support Android v5/6 again though?